# Options problem with LaTeX using AucTeX

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex, minted, shell-escape

In my file, I use the package `minted` that requires to use the option `-shell-escape` to be passed towards the processor (in this case `pdflatex`). In order to use this option with emacs and AUCTeX, I needed to add the following line into my LaTeX-file: `%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"` in the block *local variables*. So the end of my file looks like this:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: pdflatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
%%% End:
```

Every time I load that file into emacs, emacs asks me if I want to use this option, as emacs considers it "unsafe". I said yes.

However, I have an issue when I'm compiling my LaTeX-file (with package `minted`included).  The log file says that

```
Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.
```

Beyond that, I have the following error:

```
Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.
```

But I don't understand why since when I open an shell and I enter the following command:

```
`pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex`
```

then the file is compiling.

Moreover, I edited this file last week and I didn't have this problem with pygmentize. Since I have started to use *prelude* yesterday, the problem is related to that.

So how can I resolve these two problems?

Comment: You might want to ask on the `auctex` mailing list instead.

Comment: Does your AucTeX PATH contains the path where pygmentize is located?

Comment: I am running Aquamacs, AUCTeX and TeXLive on a recent MacOS.  I tried the first code example on page 7 from http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf with the given `Local Variables` section.  Emacs asks to use the unsave option, I answer yes and start (in my case) `lualatex`.  Everything went smooth.  This is the beginning of my log file: `Running `LaTeX' on `fptest' with ``lualatex --jobname=test -shell-escape --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" test.tex''
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)`

Comment: Which emacs version do you use?